# LM Roman in R Plot (R 4.1.2)

Tags: r, extrafont

I would like to have the title and axis legend in LM Roman 10 in my R plots, to better integrate them in my LateX text.

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458870/how-can-i-make-an-r-plot-use-the-latin-modern-font-family-when-saved-as-a-pdf) solution, but in R 4.1.2 does not work.

The code is the following (citing the answer to the previous question)

```
    # Run once
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
# Install **TTF** Latin Modern Roman fonts from www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman
# Import the newly installed LModern fonts, change the pattern according to the 
# filename of the lmodern ttf files in your fonts folder
font_import(pattern = "lmroman*")


# Run each time
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win") # this line only in Windows
par(family = "LM Roman 10")
hist(c(1,2,3,4,5), xlab = "Some data", main = "A title")
```

I have tried both on Windows 10 and macOS Monterey.

I have also tried to specify the full paths of the font folder.

What I see is a plot that either has the standard R font (in Windows) or has no text at all (in macOS).

Comment: Which part exactly didn't work for R 4.1.2. What code did you run?

Comment: @MrFlick the code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35989404/11578991 without changing anything. Should I update my question?

Comment: Same problem, I get this error: 

> font_import(pattern = "lmroman*")
Importing fonts may take a few minutes, depending on the number of fonts and the speed of the system.
Continue? [y/n] y
Scanning ttf files in /Library/Fonts/, /System/Library/Fonts, /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental, ~/Library/Fonts/ ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1